# How to get/view images dynamically in homepage using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrZHB.png)

```
New_model
=========

   <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class New_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $_table = "news";

    public $title;
    public $date;
    public $description;
    public $image = "default.jpg";
    public $url;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'rules' => 'required'],

            ['field' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Date',],
            // 'rules' => 'required'],

            ['field' => 'description',
            'label' => 'Description',
            'rules' => 'required']
        ];
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->db->get($this->_table)->result();
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["new_id" => $id])->row();
    }

    public function save()
    {
         $post = $this->input->post();
         // $this->new_id = uniqid();
         $this->title = $post["title"];
         $this->date = $post["date"];
         $this->description = $post["description"];
         $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
         $this->db->insert($this->_table, $this);
         // $this->url = base_url() . 'uploads/';
         $post['url'] = base_url() . 'uploads/';
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->new_id = $post["id"];
        $this->title = $post["title"];
        $this->date = $post["date"];
        $this->description = $post["description"];


        if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
             $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
        } else {
             $this->image = $post["old_image"];
        }


         $this->db->update($this->_table, $this, array('new_id' => $post['id']));
     }

     public function delete($id)
     {
        $this->_deleteImage($id);
         return $this->db->delete($this->_table, array("new_id" => $id));
     }

     private function _uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
         // $config['file_name']            = $this->new_id;
        $config['overwrite']            = true;
        $config['max_size']             = 1024; // 1MB
        // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        // $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            return $this->upload->data("file_name");
        }

        return "default.jpg";
     }

     private function _deleteImage($id)
     {
           $new = $this->getById($id);
           if ($new->image != "default.jpg") {
           $filename = explode(".", $new->image)[0];
           return array_map('unlink', glob(FCPATH."uploads/$filename.*"));
        }
     }

}

public function single($id)
        {
            $data['news'] = $this->New_model->where('new_id',$id)->order_by('new_id','desc')->get_all();
            $data['news1'] = $this->New_model->limit(5)->order_by('id','desc')->get_all();
            $this->current = 'news';
            $this->load->view(['current' => $this->current]);

            $this->load->view('news',$data);
        }


Controller
==========
public function index()
    {       
        $data["news"] = $this->New_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }

public function latestnews()
        {   
           $data['news'] = $this->New_model->where('new_id',$id)->order_by('new_id','desc')->get_all();
           $this->load->view('news',$data);
        }


view
====
 <?php
                        if (isset($news) and $news) {
                            foreach ($news as $new) {
                            ?>
                                <div class="tile-primary-content">
                                    <img  src="<?php echo $new->url . $new->image;?>" alt="image" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="tile-secondary-content">
                                    <div class="section-title-1">                                     
                                       <span class="title"><?php echo $new->title;?></span>                                      
                                     </div>            
                                    <h2 class="heading-20"><?php echo $new->date;?></h2>
                                </div>    

                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
```

I'm trying to upload an image in the dashboard with a title and date along with the image upload.

1. How to display that image on the homepage?
2. How to set the URL in the New_model?
3. How to set the links to display the images in the homepage?
4. How to set the date links?
5. The title field can be viewed in the homepage, but no image and date…

Comment: Kindly provide full code of New_model.php, so it is easy to understand and find a solution.

Comment: You've already provided the View file and I think it should work dynamically. So what are issues you facing now or any suggestions? If then kindly provide link of the captured output screenshot.

Comment: image and date are not working dynamically..what are the errors in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

**Controller: (Edited)**

```
   function index() {
        $this->data["news"] = $this->new_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view('index', $this->data);
   }

   function single_news($id) {
      $this->data['news_data'] = $this->new_model->getNewsByID($id);
      $this->load->view('single-news', $this->data); // Create New View file named single-news.php
   }

   function add_news() {
        $image_status = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $image_name = NULL;
            if ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) {
                $this->load->library('upload');

                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size'] = '1024';
                $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){
                    $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                }

                $image_name = $this->upload->file_name;
                $image_status = TRUE;
            }

            $data = array(
                'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
                'date' => $this->input->post('date')?date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('date'))):NULL,
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'image' => $image_name
            );
        }
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && $image_status && $this->new_model->addNews($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'News has been created successfully.');
            redirect('index');
        } else {
            $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('error');
            $this->data['page_title'] = 'Add News';
            $this->load->view('add_news', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

When adding new News you don't need to add the uploaded location (Not necessary).

**Model: (Edited)**

```
function getAll() {
   $q = $this->db->get('news');
   if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
      foreach($q->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      return $data;
   }
  return false;
}

function getNewsByID($id) {
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $q = $this->db->get('news');
   if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
      return $q->row();
   }
  return false;
}

function addNews($data) {
   if($this->db->insert('news', $data)){
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

**View: (Edited)**

```
<?php
     if ($news) {
       foreach ($news as $new) {
?>
        <div class="tile-primary-content">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('single_news/'.$new->id); ?>"
          <img  src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$new->image); ?>" alt="image" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-secondary-content">
          <div class="section-title-1">                                     
            <span class="title"><?php echo $new->title;?></span>                                      
          </div>            
          <h2 class="heading-20"><?php echo !is_null($new->date)?date('d.m.Y', strtotime($new->date)):' - ';?></h2>
        </div>    
<?php
      }
   }
?>
```

**single-news.php: (View)**

```
...
<img src="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$news_data->image); ?>" />
...
```

Comment: how to open the dynamic image in a seperate page while clicking the image?

Comment: what are the columns of your `news` table. Can you list out the column names so that I'll provide you a solution accordingly.

Comment: id,title,date,descrption,image

Comment: i have edited the code by adding  public function single($id) in New_model and public function latestnews() in controller....

Comment: displaying error... what is the error in public function single($id) in New_model and public function latestnews() in controller...

Comment: Kindly create another Question with displaying error code or message but before that search any solutions for that error.